# If Random variable is a function

Tags: probability, probability-density, probability-theory

The basic definition of random variable is that it is a function based on random experiment.the question is that if it is a function say f then how can it take numerical values..
           Suppose if we toss two coins and X be random variable relating no. of heads with (0,1,2) .For event of two heads say w....we have X(w)=2 is value of function X at w. and not of X itself..
  But sometimes it is written that x is a r .v taking values 0,1,2,....
   Don't it sound wrong to say function and takes values?

Answer (score 2):

A random variable is a *well defined* function `X: E -> R`, whose domain `E` is a probability space and its codomain is (generally speaking) the set of real numbers.

Intuitively, `X` is some kind of *metric* or *measurement* on the elements of `E`.

**Example 1**

Let `E` be the set of users of Stack Overflow at a given point in time, say right now. And let `X` be the function that assigns their reputation to every SO user. For example, you could calculate `P(X >= 5000)` which is the percent of SO users with a reputation of `5000` or more.

Notice that `P(X >= 5000)` is nothing but a compact notation for the subset of `E` defined as:

```
{u in E | X(u) >= 5000}
```

meaning the subset of SO users `u` with a reputation of `5000` or more.

**Example 2**

Let `E` be the set of questions in SO and `X` the function that assigns the number of votes (at certain point in time) to each question. If you pick one question `q` at random, `X(q)` would be its number of votes and we could ask for the probability of, say, `X < 0` (down-voted questions.)

Here the subset of such questions is

```
{q in E | X(q) < 0}
```

i.e., the subset of questions `q` having a negative vote count.

---

**Conclusion**

There is nothing *random* in a Random variable. The *randomness* is in the way we pick elements (or subsets) from its domain.

Answer (score 0):

Speaking of functions - **Yes**, it is safe to say that a function can take certain values. Speaking of random variables and probability, the definition I know is:

> A **random variable** assigns a numerical value to each possible outcome of a **random experiment**

This definition does indeed say that **X** (aka random variable) is a function. In your case, where it is said that **X** (as in function) can take values 0,1,2 is basically saying that the subset of the **codomain** (or even the codomain or target set itself) of function **X** is the set **{0,1,2}**, or **interval 
[0,2] ⊂ ℕ**.